# MySQL - Sort first future events then past event

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Today is : `2017-10-14`, and here is a table of event dates:

```
... 
2017-10-18
2017-10-17
2017-10-16
2017-10-14
2017-10-12
2017-10-10
2017-10-09
....
```

I want to sort the table like this

```
...
2017-10-14
2017-10-16
2017-10-17
2017-10-18
2017-10-12
2017-10-10
2017-10-09
....
```

How can I do that using MySQL?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: General rule: "Show your attempt, explain desired behaviour, current behaviour and the difference"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
ORDER  BY CASE 
            WHEN eventdate = Cast(now() AS DATE) THEN 1 
            WHEN eventdate < Cast(now() AS DATE) THEN -1 
            ELSE 0
          END DESC, 
          case when eventdate < Cast(now() AS DATE) then eventdate end desc,
          case when eventdate > Cast(now() AS DATE) then eventdate end asc
```

Comment: this is what I have looking. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the ordering you want using just two `CASE` expressions.  The first case separates current and future events from prior ones.  The second case orders current and future events ascending and prior ones descending.

```
SELECT
    date
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN date >= CURDATE() THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    CASE WHEN date >= CURDATE()
        THEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) ELSE -UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) END;
```

**Output:**

```
    date
1   14.10.2017 00:00:00
2   16.10.2017 00:00:00
3   17.10.2017 00:00:00
4   18.10.2017 00:00:00
5   12.10.2017 00:00:00
6   10.10.2017 00:00:00
7   09.10.2017 00:00:00
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 0):

```
order by 
  case when DateCol >= cast(now() as date) then DateCol
  --                   ^^ I use this cast is needed to ignore time part of comparing
  else now() - DateCol 
  end
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57c72a/19)

Comment: This seems like more query than necessary

Comment: @Strawberry I add another way also ;).

Comment: Your first query is great, but your second one isn't.  You always need to specify an ordering.  The two halves of the union don't magically "stick" togethet in any particular order.  I would fix the union query or just remove it entirely.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen None stick query has been removed ;).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL conveniently treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context.  So a simply way is:

```
where (datecol >= curdate()) desc,  -- put future dates first,
      (case when datecol >= curdate() then datecol end) asc,
      datecol desc
```

I like to have the first condition, so it is very clear what the ordering is intended to be.